# Convert string to date in Java for given format

Tags: java, android

I have a response from an API for a date field.

```
"billCycleDate":"2022-07-15T00:00:00-05:00"
```

I'm trying to convert this to a "dd-MM-yyyy" date format. The easy way is to simply extract the date from the string and then convert into the format I want. But I wanted to know if there is a 'correct' way of doing this.

The following code is what I've been using:

```
inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss Z", Locale.ENGLISH);
DateTimeFormatter outputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(localBill.getBillCycleDate(), inputFormatter);
formattedDate = outputFormatter.format(date);
```

I've tried different patterns ("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'", etc.) but none of them seem to work. It throws the following error:

```
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2022-07-15T00:00:00-05:00' could not be parsed at index 19
```

Comment: Did you try `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssxxx"` for your input date formatter, which seems to be the format your date is in?

Comment: What format is this - "2022-07-15T00:00:00-05:00"? Doesn't seem to match with any [standard datetime formats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-date-and-time-format-strings)

Comment: I think your pattern is wrong. I think you need [ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter#ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME). And since your string contains an offset, then I think that you should use either [ZonedDateTime](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/ZonedDateTime) or [OffsetDateTime](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/OffsetDateTime) (rather than `LocalDate`)

Comment: For input formatter use the built-in `DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME` and save the fiddling with your own format pattern string. Or just parse as `OffsetDateTime.parse(localBill.getBillCycleDate())` without specifying any formatter at all, and then format the resulting `OffsetDateTime` object the same way as you already do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this

```
inputFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:sszzz", Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings#zzzSpecifier

Answer (score 2):

I am not an Android developer but I believe that the following [Java] code will also work for Android.

```java
import java.time.ZonedDateTime;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Tester {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String str = "2022-07-15T00:00:00-05:00";
        ZonedDateTime zdt = ZonedDateTime.parse(str, DateTimeFormatter.ISO_OFFSET_DATE_TIME);
        System.out.println(zdt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)));
    }
}
```

Running the above code prints the following:

```
15-07-2022
```

Refer to the [Android] documentation for [DateTimeFormatter](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter) and [ZonedDateTime](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/ZonedDateTime).

### Edit

Alternatively – as indicated by @OleV.V. in his [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73284785/convert-string-to-date-in-java-for-given-format/73286751#comment129429858_73286751) to this answer – you can use [OffsetDateTime](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/time/OffsetDateTime) for which you don't need a `DateTimeFormatter` in order to parse:

```java
java.time.OffsetDateTime odt = java.time.OffsetDateTime.parse("2022-07-15T00:00:00-05:00");
System.out.println(odt.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH)));
```

Comment: It's the best solution posted so far. Still better to use `OffsetDateTime` rather than `ZonedDateTime` since the input string contains a UTC offset and no time zone. In both cases you can do without the explicit formatter if you want, matter of taste.

Answer (score -1):

Try this out.

```
  DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSXXX");
  df.setTimeZone(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
  
  try {
    return df.parse(dateStr); // pass the string variable which contains the date and time.

// Make sure your string has milliseconds too. Lack of such line will lead to an erroneous value for millisecond.

  } catch (ParseException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
  }
```

Let me know if any help is needed.

Comment: I get an error when I run the code in your answer: `java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "2022-07-15T00:00:00-05:00"`

Comment: Nononono, when java.time (the modern Java date and time API) is asked about (and even if it wasn't), please never suggest anyone to go back to the long outdated and notoriously troublesome `SimpleDateFormat` class.